# REST endpoint for WorkflowDeploymentService?

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, rest

I am trying use client-side javascript REST to work with SP.WorkflowServices. I haven't found much documentation on line, but I have found several useful endpoints like.

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptions()
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/EnumerateInstancesForSite()
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptionsByList('listguid')
```

I figured some of this out with [this msdn document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowinstanceservice_methods.aspx) and then sort of **RESTifying** it. Using that I've been able to get the subscriptions and instances using REST endpoints.

I want to also get all the definitions from my site, as far as I know that is the only place where it tells if it is a list or site workflow and some other publishing info that I need.

[Here is the same documentatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowdeploymentservice_members.aspx) for the WorkflowDeploymentService, and I tried following the same model with endpoints like:

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDeploymentService.Current/EnumerateDescriptions()
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDeploymentService/EnumerateDescriptions()
```

and so on without success. Does anybody know if there is a REST endpoint for this? I can do it with JSOM,

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = _context.get_web();
var serviceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
var _eploymentService = serviceManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService();
var definitions = deploymentService.enumerateDefinitions();

context.load(definitions);
context.executeQueryAsync();
```

But I would prefer to use REST since the rest of what I'm trying to do is using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to Andrew Connel, Workflow is one area that the Rest interface is not complete, and using CSOM may be the only way.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-csom-vs.-rest-...-my-preference-and-why

Comment: He said in 2013 " ... I also can't interact with workflows via REST." But I've found several different endpoints under Services and Instance managers that work great in SP 2013 on-prem. I'm wondering if some of the CUs have provided that? I'm going to hold out hope that somebody knows how to get the DeploymentServices manager