# REST or any other API for client side dev to get current users running workflows(Designer or OOTB or MS Flow)?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, api, ms-flow

As part of a requirement the clients would want us to create an SPFX webpart which displays all the document names and the tasks or workflows running on it for that user/current User. Is there a way in Client side with which i can get this detail? This has to be all the workflows running for current user.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: I don't have the exact answer, but for workflows look at WorkflowAssociations and for Flows you will want to dig around the CDS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Flow, but you can interact with the Workflow Services from the client side.  Here are a couple articles covering how to get that set up:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24786.sharepoint-2013online-workflow-service-in-jsom-part-1.aspx

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-the-sharepoint-workflow-services-client-side-object-model

Using the Workflow Services JSOM you can interact with the Deployment Service which you use to get the workflow definitions available on a site, the Subscription Service which you use to figure out which workflows are attached to which lists, and the Instance Service, which you would use to find currently running workflows.

*Some* of the client side functionality is available through REST endpoints like

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/[method name]
```

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229379/rest-endpoint-for-workflowdeploymentservice) has a few links that may be helpful in figuring out what REST endpoints are available, but that being said, I see no reason why you couldn't just make sure `SP.WorkflowServices.js` is loaded so that you can use the regular JSOM from your SPFx webpart.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will check and see if this helps...